# Override components like MuiTab that use media queries

Tags: css, material-ui

I'm trying to provide CSS overrides for MuiTab to increase the font-size.

Using the documentation about CSS overrides on material-ui I've managed to increase font size for most elements, however I got stuck at elements that use media queries as they produce more specific CSS rules than the ones I provide with my overrides.

theme.ts :

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core';

const fontSizeStyle = {
  fontSize: '1rem',
};

const fontFamilyStyle = {
  fontFamily: '"Ubuntu", sans-serif'
};

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTab: {
      root: {
        ...fontFamilyStyle,
        ...fontSizeStyle,
      },
      label: fontSizeStyle,
    },
  }
});

export default theme;
```

This produces following css rules applied to a MuiTab:

[image: muitab override example]

The rule is generated by the following file:

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Tab/Tab.js

```
[theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
  fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(13),
},
```

Does anyone have an example how to override this media query using createMuiTheme function? I don't have the breakpoints, so perhaps I need to specify breakpoints as well to be able to use them in my overrides

Kind regards

Answer (score 23):

I solved it by specifying it in the following way:

```js
    MuiTab: {
      root: {
        minWidth: 0,
        '@media (min-width: 0px)': {
          minWidth: 0
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

Specify it as follows

```js
let theme = createMuiTheme({});

theme = {
  ...theme,
  overrides: {
    MuiTab: {
      root: {
        [theme.breakpoints.up("xs")]: {
          minHeight: 10
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

export default theme;
```

`theme.breakpoints` exposes four helper methods to create CSS media queries:

- `theme.breakpoints.up(key)`
- `theme.breakpoints.down(key)`
- `theme.breakpoints.only(key)`
- `theme.breakpoints.between(start, end)`

Where each `key` is a breakpoint and matches with a fixed screen width. 
Allowed key values are `xs|sm|md|lg|xl`

See [material-ui docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/) for more info

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue. I read the docs about [Breakpoints](https://material-ui.com/layout/breakpoints/) and find a way for this situation but I find it kinda ugly as I have to apply the overridden styles in each `Tab` using `classes` property.

**Note: I don't know the solution for this problem using `createMuiTheme` function**

Apply the style to the `breakpoints` style. In this case,

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  mediaFont:{
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
     fontSize:fontSizeStyle.fontSize,
    },
  },
  });
```

Apply the above style to `TabLabel`

```
<Tab label="Item One" classes={{label:classes.mediaFont}} />
```

Answer (score -1):

CSS has a mechanism for forcing a less specific rule to override a more specific one: !important.

```
const fontSizeStyle = {
  fontSize: '1rem !important',
};
```

Comment: `!important` not is the solution for your bad css!

Comment: Don't use third party CSS, and handcraft it all to your standards then.

Or, just use important when you're trying to, you know, designate your rule as more important than that auto-generated by your framework.

Also, if you're going to criticise, you should provide a better solution, instead of just drive-by snark.